# Running a threadpool instead of manual thread creation to pass chunks in a function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I'm new to C++ and am trying to implement a thread pool to divide tasks and run them faster.

This is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    string str = " *some very long string* ";

    int seg = str.length() / 4;

    string dataSeg1 = str.substr(0, seg);
    string dataSeg2 = str.substr(seg, seg);
    string dataSeg3 = str.substr(seg * 2, seg);
    string dataSeg4 = str.substr(seg * 3, -1);

    std::thread first(getCount, dataSeg1);
    std::thread second(getCount, dataSeg2);
    std::thread third(getCount, dataSeg3);
    std::thread fourth(getCount, dataSeg4);

    first.join();
    second.join();
    third.join();
    fourth.join();

    for (auto x : result)
    {
        cout << x.first << " : " << x.second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have another void function `getCount` that appends the frequency count of the letters occurring from the long string to a global map `result`.

Is there a threadpool like in python3 that can do this more elegantly in C++? Because I think this manual thread initialization can be written dynamically.

Such that if `segments=7` is initialized somewhere at the start then there should be 7 datasegments and 7 threads running.

Answer (score 0):

No threadpool in offcial libs, but you can find them at github, such as https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool

Comment: Please add your answer as  a comment or explain more by yourself.